# How to select a marker on GoogleMaps programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

What goes right is that when I press a button it loads GoogleMaps, makes a marker and shows a custom info window.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
//etc.
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).showInfoWindow();
```

I want the marker to be in the state of being clicked on without the user actually having clicked on it himself, the program should do that for him
 The reason I want this is so that when the marker is selected (now by a manual user click) is it also show two icons. One to make a route the other to directly go to googlemaps with those coords.

How can I achieve that, besides just showing the infoWindow, it also selects the marker?

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is a hovering info window that is always there in addition to a hovering info window that appears when a marker is selected. Right? Having a marker "double selected" is your way of getting two hovering windows. Only, you can't double select a marker. If it's selected, selecting it again does nothing.

This is because all selecting a marker does is display an info window, which, according to the Info Window Documentation, is impossible. [Only one info window is displayed at a time](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows).

I can't tell you how to do what you want to do (because it can't be done). But here is one option of what you could do instead. Implement a [custom info window interface](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) with two subviews, one that is always visible, and one that is "gone" until the user clicks the marker.

Programmatically display the info window (just like you are already doing with `.showInfoWindow()`), then use `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()` to set a function that signals your custom infoWindow to switch the second view from "gone" to "visible".

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically 'click' like this. Bit of a hack, but such is Android.

```
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    markerClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            
            return false;
        }
    };
    
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(markerClickListener);

    markerClickListener.onMarkerClick(marker);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should implement `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` on your Map or Map Fragment

Inside Click listener, add new marker at clicked position on your map

This way you can solve your problem

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. I want the marker to be in a state which is normally gets by being clicked on without the user having to click on the marker, the program should do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
    GMAP.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(myMarker.latitude, myMarker.longitude))
            .title("My Marker"));
    GMAP.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Marker was clicked");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't this just add a clickListener to the marker? That is not what I asked. I want the marker to be in the state of being clicked on without the user actually having clicked on it himself, the program should do that for him.